# Differences between "of a degree that" and "to such a degree that"

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning, word-difference

It would be very helpful for me if someone discuss the differences between **of a degree that** and **to such a degree that**.

Sorry no context is available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mixing two different changes - one is including/omitting *such*. The other is switching between *of* and *to*. So there'll be four different cases. First, let's see about the *of* part.

> 1. The pain is of a **degree** that calls for morphine.
> 2. The **pain** is of such a degree that **it** calls for morphine.

In the first sentence, it's the **degree** that's being described. It's the **degree** that calls for (allows, rationalizes etc.) the usage of heavy drugs. One might say *...of a huge degree* or *...of a degree that's huge*.

In the second sentence it's the **pain** itself that is so intense that it requires a morphine injection. Both cases mean the same thing in practice but grammatically speaking, you need to watch what's being described.

And in the following examples, one can see that the first sentence makes sense. The second one doesn't feel right at all.

> 1. I was happy to **such a degree** that I cried.
> 2. <s>I was happy to a degree that I cried.</s>

What you **could** say is the following. This uses *to a degree* as a moderator. So you can substitute it for e.g. *somewhat*.

> I was happy **to a degree**.
>   I was happy **somewhat**.

One could also say this:

> I was happy to a degree, **so** I cried.

meaning

> I cried **because** I was so happy to a degree.

but that's not what you're looking for, probably.